# Ultrasonic Sensor With Interrupts on Nucleo board Inaccurate

Tags: delay, interrupt, sensors, nucleo, arduino-ultra-sonic

So I have the below code, it is supposed to use interrupts to measure the distance since the while loops would cause inaccurate readings due to the different functions in the project. Now the issue is I get inaccurate readings on a fresh program, I am not sure what could possibly be the issue. Thanks in advance.

```
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin) {
    if (GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_10) { // Change as per your Echo pin
        if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_10) == GPIO_PIN_SET) {
            echo_start = HAL_GetTick();
        } else {
            echo_end = HAL_GetTick();
            echo_received = 1;
        }
    }
}
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  while (1)
  {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_SET);  // Change as per your Trigger pin
          HAL_Delay(10);  // 10us delay
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
          startTime = HAL_GetTick();
          HAL_Delay(60); // 60 ms delay between each pulse

                  if (echo_received) {
                      uint32_t duration = echo_end - echo_start;
                      distance = duration * 0.343 / 2;
                      echo_received = 0;
                  }

                 HAL_Delay(500);
  }
}


  



static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : B1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LD2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LD2_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PB14 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_14;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PC10 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING_FALLING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* EXTI interrupt init*/
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI15_10_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI15_10_IRQn);

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}
```

I tried the sensor with the while loop to verify it is working but I would like to use interrupts to get the. results